# Disable root to execute normal user's file

Tags: permissions, root, execute-command

```
vim mycheck.py
print('writing in normal user')
chmod 000 mycheck.py
ls -al  mycheck.py
---------- 1 normal normal 27 Aug 23 11:01 mycheck.py
```

The file belong to the user `normal` and  set mode as `000`,`normal` user can't executed it himself.

```
python3   mycheck.py
python3: can't open file 'mycheck.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Why `root` can execute it?

```
su root
python3  /home/normal/mycheck.py
writing in normal user
```

How can make the file `mycheck.py` be executed only by its owner `normal`,at the same time disable root to execute it?

Answer (score 3):

Root has all privileges to do anything. Either `chmod` the file to what s/he wants or log in as you with `su`. (unlesss SELinux, AppArmor prevents him)

Also as a note: Execution access isn't necessary, since python "reads" the file.